# Applying css when user is at the top of the page

Tags: html, css

Trying to apply css to my navigation when user is at the top of the page. This is my code but it's not working

html

```
<script>    
  $(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 200) {
    $("#s-nav").addClass('nav-anim');
  } else $("#s-nav").removeClass('nav-anim');
  });
</script>
```

css

```
#s-nav {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

.nav-anim {
 margin: 40px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is working, but when you apply the class `.nav-anim` to `#s-nav` it will not apply `margin:40px 0;` because the `#s-nav` selector is an ***id*** and is more specific than `.nav-anim`, which is a ***class***.

If you want it to apply, you need to make the selector stronger (***id + class***): `#s-nav.nav-anim {}`

Working example:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 100) {
    $("#s-nav").addClass('nav-anim');
  } else 
    $("#s-nav").removeClass('nav-anim');
});
```

```css
#s-nav {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  transition: margin .3s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
}

#s-nav.nav-anim {         /* < --- here's the juice */
 margin: 40px 0;
}
body {
  min-height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="s-nav">S nav</div>
```

Comment: oh ok, I thought I had a bigger problem than that. Thanks!